# Running vline-node example on IIS

Tags: node.js, iis, vline

I have successfully tested the vline-node example locally, but would like to push it out to a server. I have tried to install the example as an application on an IIS8 website, placing the example code under wwwroot. I have done tried this both within the root and inside a virtual directory, pointing to the views folder. I am able to login to the application from a browser on the server, although, since javascript is turned off on the server browsers for security, so functionality is missing.

However, when I try to access the site from a remote browser I am not able to login. Actually, I can see that there is something wrong with my paths, as the include files are not found.

The more I've thought about this the more confused I've become. I'd like to run this under IIS, but wonder if that makes sense. Can someone offer a clean solution for hosting the vline-node example on a Windows Server, ideally under IIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using the node example, you'll need to make sure that node is actually running on your IIS server. Here's a SO response that may be helpful: [How to run Node.JS server for a web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16434755/how-to-run-node-js-server-for-a-web-application)

Note that in our node example the "main" file is `vline-node.js`, so use that in place of the `app.js` that is mentioned.