# node.js self-hosting on windows without iisnode

Tags: node.js, windows, socket.io, iis-8, iisnode

Sorry for if it's a duplicate but i couldn't find it.

I have an .net mvc app on windows server 2012 R2 with IIS 8.5. I will use some socket operations in my app. So i write an app in node.js with socket.io.

I want to host my node app in same server. All articles that i've found says "use iisnode". But I am not sure about that because of possible issues. Specially performance issues make me suspicious.

My questions are:

Should i trust iisnode to serve node app on windows?
or
What are any other options to host node.js app on windows without iisnode?

I've already read

[Installing and Running node.js applications within IIS on Windows - Are you mad?](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/InstallingAndRunningNodejsApplicationsWithinIISOnWindowsAreYouMad.aspx), https://tomasz.janczuk.org/2011/08/hosting-nodejs-applications-in-iis-on.html and https://tomasz.janczuk.org/2013/01/hosting-socketio-websocket-apps-in-iis.html blog posts.

Comment: You can do both, use iisnode or windows service to run your node.js app, the decision is yours. See this http://stackoverflow.com/a/16448070/3284355

Comment: Yeah I've read that SO post. And i decided to use iisnode. Because, all articles that specially pointing performace, was outdated. IISNODE has lots of improvements now. I setup my environemt. I'm testing now. I will answer my quiestion in later dates.... Thank you.

Comment: @İsa Basan ,any updates regarding this question?  I am sort of in the same boat, there doesn't seem to be much recent documentation regarding this question. Or maybe i just don't know how to ask the internet the right questions. :/

Comment: I'm using iisnode but I'm not able to get the built-in debugger working. My issue is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50720908/iisnode-debugger-error-during-websocket-handshake-unexpected-response-code-20.